# css absolute positioning over an img, that changes size

Tags: css, css-position

I thought I had it all working. an `<img>`, a `div.wrapper` around it (with `position:relative`, and an `<i class="icon-edit"></i>` with absolute position just beneath the right top position of the `<img>`. something like this:

```
<div class="userLogo" >
  <img ng-show="user.image_url"  ng-src="{{user.image_url}}" />  //data from angular, doesn't make a difference here
  <div  class="userEdit"><i class="icon-edit hand"></i></div>
</div>
```

with css (less style but you can understand):

```
.userLogo
{
  width: 233px;
  height: 233px;
  img {
    height:233px;
  }
  float: left;
  //border: 1px solid @borders;
  position:relative;
}

.userEdit
{
  background: @bajeBack;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: @lightGreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 13px;
  z-index: 50;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 3px 2px 2px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  .icon-edit{

  }
}
```

and then, playing with the webapp it hit me: The image size can change! since I don't want to use a set width/height (that would distort the proportion of some images) I just set the height (to fit the design) and let the browser resize the width accordingly.

My problem; A narrow image would break the design - the `edit` icon would be hang in air, and not on the image at all, since it's positioned according to the userLogo.

My question: how can I do the same "absolute" positioning according to the image ? since it can't be the container. please enlight me. and don't hesitate to suggest changes to the html if needed.  I'll be more the happy to learn something new!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need to constrain your image to a set space. How about using `max-height` and `max-width`.

```
.userLogo img {
   max-height: 233px; 
   max-width: 233px;
}
```

It's pretty well supported these days: http://caniuse.com/#search=max-width